# Use Launch Settings environmentVariables in IDesignTimeDbContextFactory

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, environment-variables, ef-code-first, dbcontext

```
public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    var configuration = BuildConfiguration();
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseNpgsql(configuration["StorageSettings:DbConnection"]);

    return new MyContext(builder.Options, null);
}

private static IConfigurationRoot BuildConfiguration()
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    return configuration.Build();
}
```

Here is my `launchsettings.json` file:

```
"environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
    "StorageSettings__DbConnection": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Db;Username=postgres;Password=postgres",
}
```

This the command I am starting:

```
dotnet ef migrations add 
       --project src/Infrastructure/App.Persistence/App.Persistence.csproj 
       --startup-project src/Presentation/App.WebApi/App.WebApi.csproj 
       --context App.Persistence.Context.MyContext 
       --configuration Debug SecondMigration --output-dir Migrations
```

I can't write the connection string in the `appsettings.json` file, due to client requirements; I can only write it in the `launchsettings.json`. When I try to access `configuration["StorageSettings:DbConnection"]` it's empty.